# slow down time take by domtoimage js

Tags: javascript, html

I am using [domtoimage](https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image) library to convert html (with lots of CSS) to image.

Actually I need high clarity image for printing purpose (600 DPI). So for this I scale (zoom) the html to 6.25(600/96) times, then I use domtoimage to capture it. I am successful as per my plans. My image is of high resolution and the printing clarity is also satisfactory.

But the issue is with optimization. It takes too long time for domtomimage. I know this issue is because of html scaling, but I need high resolution image.

Any idea for making this capture fast? My main focus is to reduce time taken by library to capture and create image.

Note:

1. I have also tried with phantom JS, but some css properties are not supported in it.
2. I have also tried html2canvas which has also limitation with some CSS property

Just for information I have added scale property to draw function

```
function draw(domNode, options) {
        return toSvg(domNode, options)
            .then(util.makeImage)
            .then(util.delay(100))
            .then(function (image) {
                var canvas = newCanvas(domNode);
               // canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(image, 0, 0);
                var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                if(options.scale){
                    ctx.scale(6.25,6.25);
                }
                ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
                return canvas;
            });

        function newCanvas(domNode) {
            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
             if(options.scale){
                 canvas.width = options.width || 6.25 * util.width(domNode); 
                 canvas.height = options.height || 6.25 * util.height(domNode); 
             }
             else{
                canvas.width = options.width || util.width(domNode);
                canvas.height = options.height || util.height(domNode);     
             }

            if (options.bgcolor) {
                var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                ctx.fillStyle = options.bgcolor;
                ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            }

            return canvas;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

I could speed up the image generation process by several times by skipping the font re-rendering process. I'm not sure what content you're trying to capture but if it is not font-specific, I forked and edited the library based on suggestions from several other users and it works for me. It also helped me get rid of many failed XHR requests due to CORS and is currently working on all browsers.

**Check out**: https://github.com/venkat4541/dom-to-image

This may or may not work for you based on your font usage. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will surely look into it and let you know

Comment: I need to capture it with zoom factor of 6.25. My purpose is to print this image as 600 DPI. So I need to zoom a factor of 6.25. And `dom-to-image.js` doesn't have `draw` and `newCanvas` method.

Comment: This fork is amazing! i cut down my time from 1 minute 40 seconds to 14 seconds :)

Comment: Thanks @henokg. Happy to hear it helped you :)